# Python36\Scripts starts on wrong python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypy

so I made a package that contains one python file that goes during installation to Python36\Scripts. But on WinOS, I have 3 global python interpreters.

Main is python2.7, second in use is python3.6 and third in use is  python3.7.

The package 'my_package' is installed in python3.6 in C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\my_package and contains python file settings.py

The script 'my_script.py' is installed also in python3.6 under C:\Python36\Scripts\my_script.py

So now that you know where is what here is a problem when I write in cmd my_script.py it will run it over python2.7 an exception will be raised because it is not python2.7 friendly.

In UNIX it would be solved easily with a shebang line. 
How to call my_script.py with python3.6 interpreter.

Before you answer I did try this:

- cmd is in administrator mode
- py -3.6 my_script.py start will result in [Errno 2] No such file or directory

structure of the package:

1. my_package

   2. my_package

      - __init_.py
      - settings.py
   3. scripts

      - __init_.py
      - my_script.py
   4. setup.py

---

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(name='my_package',
      version='0.1.4',
      description='Work in progress',
      long_description=long_description,
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      author=',
      author_email='',
      packages=['my_package'],
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=['SQLAlchemy', 'pandas'],
      scripts=['scripts/my_script.py']
      )
```

**my_script.py**

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
sys.stdout.write(get_python_lib())
sys.path.insert(0, get_python_lib())

from my_package.settings import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround for this problem, that will work nicely. Instead of having one script, now I have my_script.py and my_scriptV3.py... and now my_scriptV3.py has all the code that my_script.py had and my_script.py now is version handler that helps user to setup properly what version to use and requires that action only once and only in case that main python interpreter is python 2, and later every time it calls my_script.py from cmd it will use previous information and call my_scriptV3.py without any extra steps again.

Here is the code might help someone(it is not optimized):

```
import os
import sys
import pickle
import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call

python_path = r'C:\Users\{}\Documents\py_config.pkl'.format(getpass.getuser())

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    check_path = os.path.exists(python_path)
    if check_path is False:
        while True:
            sys.stdout.write('Python 2.x is not supported do you have Python 3.x? [y/n]')
            answer = raw_input()
            sys.stdout.write("\r")
            if answer.lower() not in ['y', 'n', 'yes', 'no']:
                sys.stdout.write("Answer can be y or n. Try again..\n")
                continue
            break

        if answer.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            py_versions = {}
            sys.stdout.write('\nSelect Python3 version to use\n')
            p = Popen(['py', '--list'], stdout=PIPE)
            while True:
                line = p.stdout.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                line = line.strip().strip('-')
                if line.startswith('3'):
                    line = line[:line.find('-')]
                    py_versions.update({len(py_versions): line})
            if not py_versions:
                sys.stdout.write('\nInstall Python 3 to be able to use this framework')
                exit()
            while True:
                options = ""
                for k, v in py_versions.items():
                    options += "[%s] %s\n" % (k,v)
                sys.stdout.write(options)
                answer = raw_input()
                if answer.isdigit() is False:
                    sys.stdout.write("\n Option must be numeric value. Please try again...\n")
                    continue

                selected_option = int(answer)
                if selected_option not in py_versions.keys():
                    sys.stdout.write("\n Option you entered does not exist. Please try again...\n")
                    continue

                py_version = py_versions.get(selected_option)
                if py_version is not None:
                    py_data = {'version': py_version}
                    sys.stdout.write('\nSelected Python version is %s\n' % py_version)
                    sys.stdout.write('\nChecking paths for this Python pleas wait..\n')
                    p = Popen(
                        'py -%s -c "import sys; import os; sys.stdout.write(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))" ' % py_version,
                        stdout=PIPE)
                    lines = p.stdout.readlines()
                    main_path = lines[0]

                    pycon_path = os.path.join(main_path,'Scripts','my_script.py')
                    if os.path.exists(pycon_path) is False:
                        sys.stdout.write("\n Can't locate my_script.py at {0} \n make sure you are using python "
                                         "version where you installed this package then try again...".format(pycon_path))
                        exit()

                    command = 'py -{0} {1}'.format(py_version, pycon_path)
                    py_data.update({'cmd': command})
                    with open(python_path, 'wb') as fw:
                        pickle.dump(py_data, fw)
                    call(command)

                break


        else:
            sys.stdout.write('\nInstall Python 3 to be able to use this framework')
    else:

        with open(python_path, 'rb') as fr:
            data = pickle.load(fr)
            version = data.get('version')
            sys.stdout.write('\nPython version is defined in %s\n'% python_path)
            sys.stdout.write('\nSelected Python version is %s\n' % version)
            cmd = data.get('cmd')
            call(cmd)


else:
    from Scripts.my_scriptv3 import *
    Configuration()
```

Answer (score 1):

when calling `python script.py`, the file `script.py` is found by the **operating system**, so you must give the full path to `script.py`, i.e. `python c:\python36\scripts\script.py`.

If you wish to have **python** find the script, you should call `python -m script` (with no `.py`) which will startup python and look in `sys.path` for a module named `script`. You could just call `script.py` with no preceding `python`, but that is more complicated:

- The correct python interpreter must be registered with windows as the exe to use when opening `*.py` files, and only one interpreter can be registered at a time
- The directory `c:\python36\scripts` must be on your path

Windows does not use the `#!` shebang "protocol" where you put the command to execute the file in the first line of the file